# Extract the value from the JSON Response using JSONPath Expression

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

[please see the response in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pEMg.png)

"{"id":47}"

I need to extract 47 from the above response using JSONPath Expression.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with what you've already tried?

Comment: Hi @gregsdennis, I tried to extract the value 47 from the above response. But $.id is not giving the expected result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try with this regular expression, "{"id":(.*?)}"

Comment: Hi @JyotiPrakashMallick, it didn't worked.

Comment: The response you paste it here and the image are different the regex will work for the value which paste above and for the image `"{\\"id\\":(.*?)}"`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JyotiPrakashMallick. It worked. Saved a lot of my time. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using regular expression extractor use jsonextractor& expression as $..id [json extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ZdO.png)